# How to make a dropdown menu with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to make a drop down menu in my navigation div just using CSS. I have the style and everything I want, but the only thing that seems to get messed up is the height. I have three list items that I want to appear when hovered over the link, but only one appears. I know it has something to do with the height of the nav div, but I don't know how to fix it because I don't want the purple bar to appear any taller than it is. I just want the links to drop down over top of the text below like normal. Help please?

http://www.pitt.edu/~mkm49/1052/available.html

(Yes this is for a school assignment, but I have done all the work myself I just need help getting through this one obstacle, for those of you who are weird about helping students!)

Comment: I highly recommend you check out cssplay.co.uk

Comment: This is why I hate posting from my site because people like sachleen instantly judge and think I just don't want to do the work. I did do a lot of research and _literally_ looked through the hundred of examples to find one that worked. Hence what I have so far, but when I put it into my document with my other elements it cut off the rest of my list, and I just need help fixing the height somehow so the purple doesn't get any bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about your code all wrong it seems, I read through your source, and apparently you are hiding all the menu items very far out side of the screen with `left: -999em` which is a very bad way to do this.

You should try looking into the CSS `display` rule, you can use `display: none` to hide a div, and then `display: block` or `display: inline` to show it again, dependent on if you want the item to be inline or block.

Try rewriting how your code acts with your menu items, such as a simple `display` change on hover, would suffice.

**NOTE**

You should try to keep your IDs and Classes easier to understand, currently they seem a bit unorganized and uninformative.

I hope you're able to get this working!

Comment: If you think this is the correct answer for you, then click the up arrow and/or the tick underneath to show you have your answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebug or chrome dev tools to inspect your work? You've got some overlapping issues that you should be able to figure out with a little inspection.

And a quick tip, since this is for a project... You've gone down a slippery slope of using a lot of absolute positioning in your css.  This is generally not a good practice and in an indirect way, may be the cause of your problems.
Good luck!